# PHP set PHPSESSID

Tags: php, curl, session-cookies

I am trying to set the PHPSESSID from a value I received from a CURL POST. However, it is not setting when I assign it to the session_id(). The first echo statement is the correct PHPSESSID from the curl post. However, the second echo returns empty. Any thoughts?

PHP

```
//set current session id
session_id($sessID[1]);
echo "current SessID: " . session_id();

//start session
session_start();
echo "PHPSESSID: " . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
```

Comment: You cannot echo *anything* before doing `session_start()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's superglobals are populated with data when the script starts up, and then they are **NOT** touched again by PHP for the life of the script. Your new session ID will only show up on the NEXT request, after the new session cookie's had a chance to round-trip through the client's browser.

Comment: I believe `$_SESSION` is not set until `session_start()` is called or else you wouldn't need to call `session_start()` to get the variables from `$_SESSION` on later page calls.

Comment: so is it possible to set the phpsessid cookie before a header redirect?

Comment: sure. setcookie() will set a header which goes out with the rest of the headers, INCLUDING the redirect. but that new cookie won't show up in $_COOKIE until AFTER the client returns to your site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo *anything* before doing `session_start()`. Per the docs:

> Note: To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called
> before outputing anything to the browser.

https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-start.php

The way you have it now is messing up the cookie. And you don't want to be messing up the cookies. :) The end result is the client never recognizes a session id cookie.

Comment: I removed the echo statement prior to outputting anything and it did not set the PHPSESSID cookie. Any idea why it didnt?